# tcp and apache keepalivetimouts

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp

A few weeks ago I wrote a small program which created a socket to an apache webserver and made a request.
Back then I did not know that this web server had a KeepAliveTimeout of 5 seconds.
After my first request I waited 1 minute. After this I wanted to reuse my first socket for another webserver request, but got an error.

From [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/syscalls.html#sendrecv) I learned that if recv returns 0, then the other side has closed its connection:

```
Wait! recv() can return 0. This can mean only one thing: the remote side has closed 
the connection on you! A return value of 0 is recv()'s way of letting you know this 
has occurred.
```

My questions are now:

What does Apache send when the KeepAliveTimeout is over - a FIN or a RST packet?

I know that using a TCP connection for 2 unrelated HTTP requests like in this scenario might 
not be the best thing. But in order to understand TCP more the next question is:

After my first successful http request, and before sending the next HTTP request over the same socket, would there be somehow a possibility to get informed about this keepalivetimeout TCPsocket termination of the server other than receiving 0 from the next recv() call?

Answer (score 2):

It will send a FIN. If you write a request to the server after that, send() will return -1 with errno/WSAGetLastError() = ECONNRESET.

Answer (score 1):

> would there be somehow a possibility to get informed about this keepalivetimeout tcp socket termination of the server

Yes, by reading the proper response header parameter, namely [`Keep-Alive: timeout=delta-seconds`](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-01.html):

> **'timeout' Parameter**
>
> A host sets the value of the timeout parameter to the time that the host will allows an idle connection to remain open before it is closed. A connection is idle if no data is sent or received by a host.
>
> The value of the timeout parameter is a single integer in seconds.
>
> A host MAY keep an idle connection open for longer than the time that it indicates, but it SHOULD attempt to retain a connection for at least as long as indicated.

As you can see, it's up to the host to decide. Given it only *SHOULD* try to keep the connection open as long as promised, but it isn't required that it *does*  in order to conform to the spec, so the server might decide to close and reuse the connection to serve another pending client.